# Google formating plugin -Spotless

Tags: maven, plugins

i have added a plug in like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <java>
            <googleJavaFormat>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <style>GOOGLE</style>
            </googleJavaFormat>
        </java>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

i want me code to be reformated automatically using this plug in. i have old project where i  am trying to use this

but it just list down the violation it does not auto reformat it.

> > After builing it just faild the build wd violation

i tried updating goals  apply

```
  <goals>
                    <goal>apply</goal>
                </goals>
```

but that is also not working

Answer (score 0):

Try using goal apply within process-classes phase:

> ```
>   <plugin>
>     <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>2.17.4</version>
>     <configuration>
>       <java>
>         <googleJavaFormat>
>           <version>1.7</version>
>           <style>GOOGLE</style>
>         </googleJavaFormat>
>       </java>
>     </configuration>
>     <executions>
>       <execution>
>         <goals>
>           <goal>check</goal>
>         </goals>
>       </execution>
>       <execution>
>         <id>apply</id>
>         <phase>process-classes</phase>
>         <goals>
>           <goal>apply</goal>
>         </goals>
>       </execution>
>     </executions>
>   </plugin>
> ```